# jsx unexpected token passing array of object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

```
<SettingsDropdown labelName="Settings" items={[
    {name:'Feature Listing', handler:{this.handle_dropdown_featureListing}, divider:true}
 ]}/>
```

What's wrong with my above syntax?

I do have

`handle_dropdown_featureListing = () => { //something }` but I got unexpected token error still.

Answer (score 1):

```
handler:{this.handle_dropdown_featureListing}
```

here you have an object literal that does not have a key.

It must be

```
handler:{keyName: this.handle_dropdown_featureListing}
```

or whatever name you need.

Or if you need to pass a single function reference - just remove the curly braces:

```
handler: this.handle_dropdown_featureListing
```